# How to get the metadata in real time with Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-videoview, android-camera2

I need to get the current ISO, exposure time and focal length in numeric variables. If it cannot be done then I would like to get that metadata data from a previously saved video.

Answer (score 0):

That information is available in CaptureResults, which are provided per-frame in the [capture callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback) that you pass into either [capture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.html#capture(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) or [setRepeatingRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.html#setRepeatingRequest(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback,%20android.os.Handler)).

However, not all devices provide this information - any device that lists the [MANUAL_SENSOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MANUAL_SENSOR) capability does include it, which means all devices that are at least [FULL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL) hardware level will do it.  Some LIMITED devices will probably list them as well.

That information isn't generally stored in metadata of saved videos, unfortunately, though it's frequently available in EXIF for still images.